# What is utteranceID parameter in Openears ios library callback?

Tags: openears

the callback of openears is

```
- (void) pocketsphinxDidReceiveHypothesis:(NSString *)hypothesis recognitionScore:(NSString *)recognitionScore utteranceID:(NSString *)utteranceID
```

hypothesis is the text itself and score is self explained. what is utteranceID?

thanks allot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything significant, you can ignore this parameter. It is just an artifact of a very old pocketsphinx API.

Originally in pocketsphinx the API allowed to set the ID for every utterance it starts recognizing, so that in pocketsphinx log the recognized results are attributed to a certain wav file. Now there is no much need in that and this parameter will be removed from pocketsphinx API most likely.

Comment: I included it in OpenEars on the theory that it might be useful for the developer to have a string that could be used as a key for storing results in a dictionary, but it isn't going to be tragic if it goes away since it's easy enough to increment your own utterance count.